# How to sort the content of an array of objects inside an array of object with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my data:

```
User: [
   {
      username: 'Alice',
      hobbies: [
         { place: 'garden',
           tool: 'scissors'
         },
         {
           place: 'montain',
           tool: 'coat'
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      username: 'Joe',
      hobbies: [
         { place: 'garden',
           tool: 'scissors'
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I try to extract the 'hobbies' of user 'Alice' and sort them by 'place'.
I need to use the MongoDB/Mongoose function for sorting, not something like .sort((a,b) => a.url > b.url ? 1 : -1).

I have a function like that:

```
async function findPlaceSort(username, sortElement, sortDirection) {
   const sortedPlaces = await User.findOne({username: username})
                                  .hobbies
                                  .sort({[sortElement]: sortDirection});
   return sortedPlaces;
}
```

I call the function with **findPlaceSort('Alice', 'place', 1)**

I've tried many variations without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a mongoDB version >= 5.2, you can use the `$sortArray` operator in a projection. Simply use the following code in order to achieve this:

```
User.findOne({username: username}).project({
  hobbies: {
    $sortArray: { input: "$hobbies", sortBy: { place: 1 } }
  }
});
```